# Load view by current URL last segment in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to load view content page when url last segment matched. When click a link which get link in url like `http://192.168.20.2/vtp/attendance/rawAttendance` then load the `rawAttendance` view and when I click other link which last segment is `getAttendance` then it's also load the same same view not `getAttendance`. How do get this done?

```
    $last = $this->uri->total_segments();
    $lastSegment = $this->uri->segment($last);
    if ($this->input->post("fromAjax")) {
        if($lastSegment == "rawAttendance"){
            $this->load->view('attendance/rawAttendance', $data);
        }else if($lastSegment == "getAttendance"){
            $this->load->view('attendance/getAttendance', $data);
        }else {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CI has its inbuilt helper for knowing controller name and method name.

```
 $classname = $this->router->fetch_class();
 $methodname = $this->router->fetch_method();
 if ($this->input->post("fromAjax")) {
     if($classname == "attendance" && $methodname == "rawAttendance"){
            $this->load->view('attendance/rawAttendance', $data);
        }else if($classname == "attendance" && $methodname == "getAttendance"){
            $this->load->view('attendance/getAttendance', $data);
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sir, this is not working. But I found another way that I show you to edit the code, please take a look.

Comment: or am I didn't load the helper? which helper need load for this?

Comment: you have to load the url helper. $this->load->helper("url");

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter is a basic MVC framework - so everything starts with the controller. From the code you've written, I assume you already have your routes, etc configured to point at the method you've placed in your question.

You can simplify things quite a bit from the way you have them. Using the CI helper for controller/method is a bit helpful, but I think you're looking for something a little more elastic in your approach to dynamically load a view based on your last URI segment.

Try something like this:

```
// Get your last URI segment
$last = $this->uri->total_segments();
$lastSegment = $this->uri->segment($last);

/** 
* Do whatever logic you need to do to calculate your data
*/
// ...

/** 
* Load the view
*/
$this->load->view( 'attendance/' . $lastSegment, $data );
```

This could probably be better architected using the CI routes capability though. For instance, if you have several view folders and view files within, it would be best practice to organize those and better cement your URI structures so that each URI segment plays a specific role:

#### CI routes.php

```
$route["vtp/(:any)/(:any)"] = "path_to_method";
```

#### Method

```
$dir  = $this->uri->segment(2);
$view = $this->uri->segment(3);

$this->load->view( $dir . "/" . $view, $data );
```

Comment: Sir I tried with the first way you define but no luck.